# How to enable optionalChaining plugin for Prettier Now extension?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Getting this error for files that use optional-chaining:

> You can only use optional-chaining when the 'optionalChaining' plugin is enabled

How do i enable this plugin?

I also tried ignoring the line using `//prettier-ignore` but that isn't working.

Comment: got any solution ?

Comment: @YogeshwarTanwar Nope :-/

Comment: i changed to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode and this extension is working fine

Comment: @YogeshwarTanwar interesting, thanks for the info.